# Asp.net mvc5 WPF authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, cookies

I'm currently playing around with asp.net / MVC5 so I had an idea I wanted to create a WPF login so I can use the login the wpf app with my asp.net info. I assume I have to Create a login form onto WPF and send it to you MVC website, the server verifies them and if the credentials are correctly it emits an authentication cookie which is sent back to the client. The client stores this cookie for further authentication.

So this means you will need to send a POST request to the MVC website that verifies the username and password, then the server returns a cookie which is stored by the client in a CookieContainer.
How ever I am rather stuck on how I would go ahead and do this.

Comment: This is quite a big topic - probably too big for a single question. I found the materials here really useful for setting up Identity 2.0 authorization for both MVC and Web API 2 projects: http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/04/20/ASPNET-MVC-and-Identity-20-Understanding-the-Basics.aspx . The WPF client code for calling these will vary depending on whether you use cookies or bearer tokens.

Answer (score 0):

As @Goobering pointed out in the comment above, this is too big of a question to be answered on a stack overflow post. You're looking for tutorials. More importantly, is this WPF app only going to reach out to the MVC webiste for authentication and/or authorization, or are you going to get other data as well?

My suggestion is that you make a WCF authorization web service that is hosted on the same website as your MVC. Integrating identity into WCF would be easy, and then integrating WCF into WPF apps is even simpler. This would also support getting any other data you need from the MVC website. Here are some links:

http://www.codemag.com/article/0611051

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748498.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/802435/Authentication-and-Authorization-with-ASP-NET-Iden

[Validating a user in WCF using ASP.net Identity 2.0 Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259520/validating-a-user-in-wcf-using-asp-net-identity-2-0-framework)